# Is there a Swift built-in for a default dict, similar to Array(repeating: 0, count: x)?

Tags: swift

Is there a way to create a default dictionary for counting Characters/Strings/whatever? Python has the convenient Counter() class, but I can't find anything for Swift that can just instantiate full of whatever, similar to Array(repeating: 0, count: x). I get that I can make my own. I'm asking if there's something like that in Foundation already... because I can't find it. Thanks!

**Update**
Here's are the closest two answers, from those below:
via @matt

```
let s = "abracadabra"
let letters = s.map {String($0)}
var countedLetters = [String:Int]()
letters.forEach {countedLetters[$0, default:0] += 1}
countedLetters // ["b": 2, "a": 5, "r": 2, "d": 1, "c": 1]
```

and others:

```
let letters: [Character] = ["a", "b", "c"]
let countedLetters: [Character: Int] = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: zip(letters, repeatElement(1, count: letters.count)))
print(countedLetters)
```

I was just hoping for an abstraction sitting on top of all that, similar to Python's Counter().

It apparently doesn't exist. Thank goodness for extensions :)

**Old example question**

For example:

```
let letters = ["a", "b", "c"]
let countedLetters: [Character: Int] = Dictionary(default: 1, forKeys: letters)
print(countedLetters)
// "a": 1
// "b": 1
// "c": 1
```

Comment: Based on the answers, there is some confusion about what you results you want. What results do you want if `letters` is `let letters = ["a", "c", "a", "a", "b", "c"]`, for example?

Comment: Sure, I can see where my question is confusing. I'll update it.

Comment: Wait, what? You want to count the number of occurrences of a letter in an array of characters and create a dictionary of the counts of each?

Comment: Your update doesn't clarify what result you want. Both answers you quote will give very different answers for the example I gave in my first comment.

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
var countedLetters = [String:Int]()
letters.forEach {countedLetters[$0, default:0] += 1}
```

Example:

```
let s = "abracadabra"
let letters = s.map {String($0)}
var countedLetters = [String:Int]()
letters.forEach {countedLetters[$0, default:0] += 1}
countedLetters // ["b": 2, "a": 5, "r": 2, "d": 1, "c": 1]
```

Comment: I supposed that's probably similar to what Python's Counter() class does under the hood. I was just looking for an abstraction above all that.

Comment: Sure, I understand. Any of the approaches you're being shown here is as "built-in" as you're going to get.

Comment: The near-equivalent of Python's `Counter` is `NSCountedSet`. It's a very ugly interface in Swift in the general case (because it relies on `Any`), but for the purposes of just counting things, it actually works fine in Swift.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Dictionary init(uniqueKeysWithValues:)`. This is much like in the example shown in the documentation.

```
let letters: [Character] = ["a", "b", "c"]
let countedLetters: [Character: Int] = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: zip(letters, Array(repeating: 1, count: letters.count)))
print(countedLetters)
```

Output:

> ["a": 1, "b": 1, "c": 1]

Comment: Yeah, I was about to give that one too.

Comment: Ever so slightly nicer: `zip(letters, repeatElement(1, count: letters.count))` (just because it avoids creating an array; it's a shame that Swift doesn't have an "infinite repeat sequence")

Comment: @RobNapier I wasn't familiar with `repeatElement`. Good to know, thanks.

Comment: "Back in my day", we used to `(0...count).lazy.map { _ in 1 }`. Yucky!

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to count letters, you don't really need it. You can just use [`Dictionary.subscript(_:default:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2894528-subscript)

```
extension Sequence where Element: Hashable {
    func histogram() -> [Element: Int] {
        return self.reduce(into: [:]) { dict, element in dict[element, default: 0] += 1 }
    }
}

print("aaabbcc".histogram())
```

There's still a slight difference in usage. Python's `defaultdict` defines the default value for missing keys during the creation of the `defaultdict`, whereas this subscript asks for the default value at the time of the access. It's more flexible, but might be less convenient. It depends on the use-case.

If this usage pattern doesn't fit your bill, then you can create your own `DefaultDictionary`, wrapping a dict, a default value, and using the `Dictionary.subscript(_:default:)` implicitly. Here's a rough start:

```
public struct DefaultDictionary<K: Hashable, V> {
    public var dict = [K: V]()
    public var defaultValueProducer: (K) -> V

    public init(dict: [K: V], defaultValue: V) {
        self.init(dict: dict, defaultValueProducer: { _ in defaultValue })
    }

    public init(dict: [K: V], defaultValueProducer: @escaping (K) -> V) {
        self.dict = dict
        self.defaultValueProducer = defaultValueProducer
    }

    private func produceDefaultValue(forKey key: K) -> V {
        return self.defaultValueProducer(key)
    }

    public subscript(_ key: K) -> V {
        get { return self.dict[key, default: produceDefaultValue(forKey: key)] }
        set { self.dict[key, default: produceDefaultValue(forKey: key)] = newValue }
    }

    func reallyContains(key: K) -> Bool {
        return self.dict[key] != nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As Rob mentions, the closest you'll get in Cocoa is the Objective-C class NSCountedSet:

```
//Turn a string into an array of characters
let string = "aabcccdeeeef"
let array = string.map {String($0)}

//Turn the array into a counted set.
let counted = NSCountedSet(array: array)

//print the entries in the counted set. Note that sets don't preserve order
counted.forEach{ print($0, ":", counted.count(for:$0)) }

//Or if you want to use a counted set to build a dictionary of counts:
var result = [String: Int]()
array.forEach { result[$0] = counted.count(for: $0) }
print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Two more options:

```
let results = Dictionary(grouping: s) { $0 }
    .mapValues { $0.count }
```

That seems nice and intuitive. Not terribly efficient, but that’s not critical unless you’re doing this on *Moby Dick.*

Or:

```
let results = s.reduce(into: [:]) {
    $0[$1, default: 0] += 1
}
```

Both are easily collapsed into one line, but I don’t particularly think that improves the readability.